# ODATA URI Query Expand from FK to PK

Tags: .net, odata, wcf-data-services

Have WCF Data Service from ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Three tables

```
docSVsys: PK ID 
          ,sValue


docSVtext: composite PK sID, fieldID 
           ,mValue

        sID has FK relation to docSVsys,ID
        fieldID has FK Relation to docFieldDef.ID

docFieldDef PK, ID
            ,fName
```

docFieldDef is a small semi static table the relates a fieldID to a field name

Can expand from PK to FK - this works

```
  http://localhost:64638/WcfDataService1.svc/docSVsys(1)?$expand=docSVtext
```

Cannot expand from this FK to PK - this fails.  Can I make this work?

```
  http://localhost:64638/WcfDataService1.svc/docSVtext?$top=1&$expand=docFieldDef
```

SO is not for commentary but.  ODATA and EF are good tools.  This was just a lot lot of data that did not map into an automated model.  Rather than implement ODATA I just added some specific WCF services.

Was not successful in intercepting the TSQL in the .NET code but was able to capture the TSQL using using SSMS Profiler.  It was a valid (but ill-formed) query timing out.  It does a join from a table of 3.3 million records to a table with 100 records and then processes the top 1.  On the 3.3 million table the join is the second int of a composite key.  The join is not even direct - the join is via a sub-query.  Re-factored to a direct join and still long query (2:30).  The sort order was on second component of the PK and then by the first (of the larger table).  Changed the sort order to first component, second component and the query went to 0 (instantaneous).  BOTH sort orders still had the same query plan.  This is also an app with a UI and no query takes no longer than 1 second but all hand crafted TSQL.

Want an ODATA interface but need to both limit the type of queries and need to hand craft the TSQL.   Could go down a path of Custom Data Service Provider and implement iQueryable but that is very hard and does not solve the first problem of limit the type of queries (not allow a stupid query).  Is there a way be ODATA compliant but limit the type of queries (and craft the TSQL).  The purpose of ODATA for this app is to export large volumes based on some very simple criteria.

Interesting this works

```
  http://localhost:64638/WcfDataService1.svc/docSVtext(fieldID=101,sID=1)?$expand=docFieldDef
```

And this works (which FK back to PK)

```
  http://localhost:64638/WcfDataService1.svc/docSVtext?$top=1&$expand=docSVsys
  (this may be a config issue - will review the keys - keys relationships look in order)
  The only difference I see it that is where it walks the name of the key was the same  in the two tables and where it failed the name of the key changed.
```

This works but looking at this data in this order is of no value

```
  http://localhost:64638/WcfDataService1.svc/docFieldDef?$top=1&$expand=docSVtext
```

Fiddler on the failed

```
> # Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
> 6 500 HTTP    localhost:64638 /WcfDataService1.svc/docSVtext?$top=1&$expand=docFieldDef   250 no-cache
>   application/xml iexplore:3188            GET
> /WcfDataService1.svc/docSVtext?$top=1&$expand=docFieldDef HTTP/1.1
> Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */* Accept-Language: en-us
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0;
> Trident/5.0) Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Connection: Keep-Alive
> Host: localhost:64638 Cookie:
> ASP.NET_SessionId=l1qpumn5xuopnsyapavocw3a
> 
> 
> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Server: ASP.NET Development
> Server/10.0.0.0 Date: Thu, 28 Jun 2012 23:03:32 GMT X-AspNet-Version:
> 4.0.30319 DataServiceVersion: 1.0; Content-Length: 250 Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/xml Connection: Close
> 
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?> <error
> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
> <code></code>   <message xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred while
> processing this request.</message> </error>
```

Per request from MarkStaffo turn on detail. Command:

```
http://localhost:64638/WcfDataService1.svc/docSVtext?$top=1&$expand=docFieldDef
```

Mark the timeout part makes no sense at it is (supposed) to hit a small table against the PK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"> <code/> <message xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred while processing this request.</message> -<innererror> <message>An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.</message> <type>System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException</type>
<stacktrace> at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() at System.Data.Services.Providers.BasicExpandProvider.ExpandedQueryable`1.GetEnumerator() at System.Data.Services.Providers.BasicExpandProvider.ExpandedQueryable`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() at System.Data.Services.WebUtil.GetRequestEnumerator(IEnumerable enumerable) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.SerializeResponseBody(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleNonBatchRequest(RequestDescription description) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()</stacktrace> -<internalexception> <message>Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.</message> <type>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException</type> <stacktrace> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)</stacktrace> </internalexception> </innererror> </error>
```

If you open the image in another tab you can zoom.
[image]

Comment: Expansion from the FK end of a relationship to the PK end should absolutely work, e.g. http://services.odata.org/(S(readwrite))/OData/OData.svc/Products(0)?$expand=Category&$select=*,Category/*.  Can you expand (no pun intended) on what the failure is? The table names in the URL don't seem to match the schema you laid out at the top, could that be it?

Comment: The URI was cut and paste - it is good.  The tables I keyed in by hand.  Also have docMVtext that is like a the multi brother to docSVtext and behave properly.  The link that fails just says "Web SiteCannot Display The Page".  I will try and past the Model.

Comment: Can you run Fiddler and see what you're actually getting back when you try to hit that URL?

Comment: @MarkStafford-MSFT done and some updates to the question.  This is getting interesting.

Comment: yeah, looks like a problem deeper down in your model. Next step is to turn on the passing of exceptions, as in Phani's blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx

Comment: @MarkStafford-MSFT See detailed debugging added to question.  If you need anything else please let me know.  I think SQL is getting bad syntax but the debug does not show what is getting sent to SQL.  This is Express so I don't have Profiler but I do have a box with full SQL 2008 R2 if you need.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13195/discussion-between-mark-stafford-msft-and-blam)